# How do I uninstall Travel Mate App in Android?

Tags: android, github, uninstallation

It has been some time now that I installed Travel mate.
https://github.com/project-travel-mate/Travel-Mate/tree/master/Android

**But the problem is:** I can't uninstall it now. :(

Every time I click on Uninstall button, the next screen covers the full screen.

[image: Travel Mate App]

[image: ![Travel Mate App - Full Screen]

I have tried searching it's apk file, but couldn't find it in my android/data/ or other directories.

Is there any option to remove this app without installing any 3rd party app or without doing factory-reset.

**Phone Confi.:**

- Model: Coolpad 3600I
- Android Version: 6.0.1
- Resolution: 1920*1080

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using ADB. Connect device to your computer and follow instructions.

First of all you need to get serial number of connected device:

```
adb devices -l
```

You will see something like that:

> List of devices attached
>   **FA7B51A02805**           device usb:336592896X product:walleye model:Pixel_2

Serial number marked as a bold.
Use serial number to get list of all 3rd party applications installed on your device.

```
adb -s {serial number} shell pm list packages -3
```

After that you can delete app using next adb command:

```
adb uninstall {app package}
```

Comment: Thank you. It says, pm list packages -3: not found.

Comment: Ok you have to specify device that you want to use.   
List of devices:   
`adb devices -l`   
Then run    
`adb -s {device serial} shell "pm list packages -3"|cut -f 2 -d ":"`

Comment: After running `adb shell`. It gives me `shell@CP3600I:/ $` & when I run `adb devices -1` It says `/system/bin/sh: adb: not found` I did tried with my phone's IMEI no. Looks like I have to brush up my adb commands.

Comment: Yes. I have checked it yesterday only. It didn't solved my issue. Invested 2 hours on this today as well. Checked my Environment Variables twice. Since `cut` wasn't recognized as a internal or external command. Also, directories had permission issue, and don't want to root it. So I guess I have to Reset to Factory Settings only. Thanks for your help @oss !!

Comment: Oh, sorry. It was my mistake. I have adjusted answer again. it should be `-s` instead of `-l` in second command.